Need to Overide the default password stored in properties file Springboot
Override the value of the default Spring db password with value fetched from another service on start up and start the application, The app should enable the database with the credentials fetched
"spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=tester" and replace this with the valuefrom service.

You can create a custom configuration class and define it there overriding the prefix to identify current url
for example!
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    CredentialService.Credentials credentials = credentialService.getCredentials();
    dataSourceBuilder.username(credentials.getUsername());
    dataSourceBuilder.password(credentials.getPassword());
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
}

Hope this helps!
Happy Coding :)
